# PDF and CDF of Sum of 2 dice

Tags: probability, dice

i'm trying to obtain the PDF and CDF of the sum of 2 dice toss.

There are tons of elementary exercise where is asked to find the exact probability,

but what about the PDF and CDF?

i thought this is a convolution of discrete uniform PDF. but i don't know where to start to find it.

it's like $P(X_1+X_2<y)=$ but from here i don't know how to continue... i can't substitute $1/n=X_1$ and $1/n=X_1$

this would make nosense.

Thank You

Comment: PDF is not applicable here; instead, you need PMF (probability mass function) because the sum takes discrete values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the "exact probability of the sum" *is* the PDF.

$\mathsf P(X_1{+}X_2{=}y)=\dfrac 1{36}\times\begin{cases}(y-1) &:& y\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}\\[1ex] (13-y) &:& y\in\{8,9,10,11,12\}\\0 &:& \textsf{else}\end{cases}$

And the accumulation of this is the CDF.

$\mathsf P(X_1{+}X_2{\leq}y)=\dfrac 1{72}\times\begin{cases}0&:& y\leq 1\\[1ex]\lfloor y\rfloor(\lfloor y\rfloor-1) &:& \lfloor y\rfloor\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}\\[1ex] 25\lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor y\rfloor^2-84 &:& \lfloor y\rfloor\in\{8,9,10,11\}\\[1ex] 72 &:& y\geq 12 \end{cases}$

Comment: Hey Graham, Thank you. i Would like to know the general method to obtaining this. i Don't know the convolution and i think i going to study asap. But i can't get what you did. For example what should we get if we toss and sum 3 tetrahedron?

Comment: alex i asked how to obtain a pmf and cdf of a sum, you answered posting the value of the pmf. it's like i'm asking "how do i obtain an exponential pdf?" and you say " λexp-(λx) ". tot nosense

Comment: @Alex see the floor function. $\lfloor 2.5\rfloor = 2$

Comment: Graham, yes, I expected that you use floor in the formulas $y(y-1)$ etc. Otherwise the formula produces different answers for $y=2$ vs $y=2.5$

Comment: @Carlo  For $y$ the sum of results for two six-sided dice, each value of $y\in \{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ has $(y-1)$ equally probable outcomes.  For each value of $yin\{14-2,14-3,14-4,14-5,14-6\}$, each such value has $(14-y)-1$ equally probable outcomes.  Hence the PDF.  The CDF accumulates the probabilities.  Easily viewed by imagining a six by six grid of results.

Comment: @Alex.  Point.  Thank you.

Comment: @Carlo For three tetrahedron, a four by four by four cube.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank You

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to get a sum of $2$? We must get $1$ and then $1$ again with probability $\frac{1}{36}$.

How many ways are there to get a sum of $3$? We must either get a $1$ and then $2$ or vice versa with probability $\frac{2}{36}$.

How many ways are there to get a sum of $4$? We must either get a $1$ and then $3$, a $3$ and then $1$, or a $2$ and a $2$, giving a probability of $\frac{3}{36}$

Carrying on in this manner, we find that the probabilities appear to follow triangular shape. As commented, letting $X$ be the sum of the the two die, $X$ is a discrete random variable so we need a pmf.

$$ p_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{36} & x = 12 \\
\frac{2}{36} & x=11 \\
\frac{3}{36} & x=10 \\
\frac{4}{36} & x=9 \\
\frac{5}{36} & x=8 \\
\frac{6}{36} & x=7 \\
\frac{5}{36} & x=6 \\
\frac{4}{36} & x=5 \\
\frac{3}{36} & x=4 \\
\frac{2}{36} & x=3 \\
\frac{1}{36} & x=2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} $$

If you wish to construct a probability density function, despite it not making much sense in this situation, you could so something like

$$ f_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{36} & x \geq 12 \\
\frac{2}{36} & 11 \leq x \lt 12 \\
\frac{3}{36} & 10 \leq x \lt 11 \\
\frac{4}{36} & 9 \leq x \lt 10 \\
\frac{5}{36} & 8 \leq x \lt 9 \\
\frac{6}{36} & 7 \leq x \lt 8 \\
\frac{5}{36} & 6 \leq x \lt 7 \\
\frac{4}{36} & 5 \leq x \lt 6 \\
\frac{3}{36} & 4 \leq x \lt 5 \\
\frac{2}{36} & 3 \leq x \lt 4 \\
\frac{1}{36} & 2 \leq x \lt 3 \\
0 & x \lt 2 \\
\end{cases} $$

And the cumulative density function would be something like

$$ F_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
1 & x \geq 12 \\
\frac{35}{36} & 11 \leq x \lt 12 \\
\frac{33}{36} & 10 \leq x \lt 11 \\
\frac{30}{36} & 9 \leq x \lt 10 \\
\frac{26}{36} & 8 \leq x \lt 9 \\
\frac{21}{36} & 7 \leq x \lt 8 \\
\frac{15}{36} & 6 \leq x \lt 7 \\
\frac{10}{36} & 5 \leq x \lt 6 \\
\frac{6}{36} & 4 \leq x \lt 5 \\
\frac{3}{36} & 3 \leq x \lt 4 \\
\frac{1}{36} & 2 \leq x \lt 3 \\
0 & x \lt 2 \\
\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the outcome of the first and second dice. We are interested in their sum $X = X_1 + X_2$. It is important to note that since $X$ can only take on a finite number of outcome, namely 2 to 12, it is still discrete.

You could try convolution. Note the outcomes here are so simple that you could just enumerate them. Look at look at the probability table [here](https://wizardofodds.com/gambling/dice/). Essentially you will just count the number of outcome associated to each sum. Then you get $P(X=k) =$ the number of outcome associated to the sum k / 36.

CDF is defined for both discrete and continuous setting. Here you could just look at the table and for each k, come up with a formula to include the "triangle" that include all the outcomes lower than k.

Hope this helps.